# How to compute the number of extra samples added by LAME or FFMPEG

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg, wav, lame

I am attempting to build a MP3 decoder / parser in Python which supports files encoded by LAME or FFMPEG.

My encoding shell script is shown here:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in wav/*.wav; do
    i=${i##*/};
    lame --nores --strictly-enforce-ISO -t --cbr -b 64 -h "wav/${i}" "mpeg/lame/${i%.wav}.mp3";
    ffmpeg -i "wav/${i}" -codec:a libmp3lame -qscale:a 2 "mpeg/ffmpeg/${i%.wav}.mp3";
done
```

This scripts reads WAVE files located in `./wav/` and produces a controlled-bitrate MP3 of 64kbps in my `./mp3/lame/` directory, and a variable-bitrate MP3 of quality 2 in my `./mp3/ffmpeg/`.

I have written a Python script that iterates through both resultant MP3s, counting the number of frames and samples. Both the LAME and FFMPEG results are equivalent (in terms of frames and samples), but their binary files are different.

The LAME/FFMPEG sample count was done by iterating through the binary MP3 files, locating and parsing the frame header, then using the MP3 spec to determine the number of samples per frame.

- Number of MP3 data-frames: 112 (ignoring the Xing/Info first frame)
- Number of output frames: 112*576 = **64512**

Here is a comparison of the sample count for a single 4-second input file:

- Input WAV # of samples = 62996
- Output LAME/FFMPEG # of samples = 64512
- Difference = 1516

I understand that [according to the LAME FAQ file](http://lame.sourceforge.net/tech-FAQ.txt), resultant MP3 files are zero padded in the front and back to make sure the inverse MDCT is performed properly, but also because the windows overlap.

What I can't ascertain from the above FAQ, or from any previous StackOverflow post, is how to compute the number of artificially added samples. If I can be sure that all 1516 of these samples are zeros, and I can be sure of their position in the bytestream, I'd like to be able to confidently toss them out. Since there are 1516 "extra" samples and there are 576 samples per frame for a V2LIII encoding, then there must be more than two (but less than three) erroneous MPEG frames here.

Is anyone here savvy enough with MPEG encoding/decoding to know how many samples are added, and in which frames those samples will be in? In other words, will the first frame and last frame always contain blank data, or are there more frames?

Comment: I am confident that this can be solved somehow, since, if I encode a WAV file using the command-line LAME utility, then open the MP3 up in Audacity and export another WAV, the resultant file has the same number of samples as the original WAV. So somehow, LAME is able to keep track of what it zero-pads...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to decode the resultant MP3s with ffmpeg with loglevel debug mode.

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp3 -f null - -v 48
```

Within the console output, you'll have this line

```
[mp3 @ 0000000002be28c0] pad 576 1105
```

This doesn't include the fixed encoder delay.

So the actual skipped sample count is shown by these two lines

Start padding in first frame:

```
[mp3 @ 0000000002e6bb80] skip 1105/1152 samples
```

End padding in last frame:

```
[mp3 @ 0000000002e6bb80] discard 576/1152 samples
```

This info is only present if the Xing header is written.

Comment: Thanks for responding! So running the decoder, here are all the logs which mentioned either "discard" or "skip".
`[mp3 @ 0x7faf18809400] demuxer injecting skip 0 / discard 411
[mp3 @ 0x7faf19008c00] discard 411/576 samples
[mp3 @ 0x7faf19008c00] skip 0 / discard 411 samples due to side data
[mp3 @ 0x7faf19008c00] skip 1105 / discard 0 samples due to side data
[mp3 @ 0x7faf19008c00] skip 529/576 samples
[mp3 @ 0x7faf19008c00] skip whole frame, skip left: 529`
So from this, I see my 1516 discrepancy is equal to 1516 = 411 + 1105. So that's good.

Comment: Or actually, like you said, `[mp3 @ 0x7faf18809400] pad 576 940` this pad statement accounts for the discrepancy. It's 1516 = 576 + 940. So will it always be 576 samples in the front and 940 in the back? Is there a formula to compute these pad values?

Comment: It depends on the frame size and sampling frequency. For each permutation, for a given encoder, it should be fixed. (Assuming the file isn't corrupt or truncated).